# React "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" causes "not a child" errors on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a site which allows users to write content in BBCode and then parses the BBCode to HTML for rendering on the site. I am converting part of the site to use React. As far as I know, the only way of rendering raw content in React is to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: someHtmlString } }` on a child element.

When I use this method, however, I get errors when removing the node with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or modifying any of its neighbors. The errors are either `The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node` or `The node to be removed is not a child of this node`.

The Node in question that is not a child of some other node appears to be the `<span>` tag on which I am "dangerously setting innerHTML", as I inspected it in the debugger and its child nodes are the rendered BBCode.

Is there a reason why the DOM hierarchy is getting corrupted like this? Do I need to do a multi-stage update when removing this node to first set its innerHTML to null, then re-render, *then* remove the node itself?

Comment: `I get errors when removing the node with dangerouslySetInnerHTML` how do you remove that node? Can you show some code+markup so we get an idea what you're dealing with?

Comment: It's mounted conditionally, so `{ this.state.editing ? /* ...textarea, buttons, etc */ : <span dangeroulySetInnerHTML={{ __html: model.html }}/> }`

When `this.state.editing` becomes true, the error occurs because it replaces the `<span>` with the components used for editing

Comment: If I leave that `<span>` rendered all the time and have `{ this.state.editing && /* elements used for editing */ }`, I get the "node before which is not a child" error. It's like somehow the span becomes detached from the DOM hierarchy after being mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the cause of this...I can't be positive this was the cause, but changing it fixed the issue.

The rendered BBCode appears to have contained elements that are not valid children of a `<span>`, so when the `innerHTML` was set, the node somehow just got removed from the DOM hierarchy (even though it rendered completely fine in the browser, with the BBCode content and everything).

I restructured the component to set the `innerHTML` of the parent `<div>` (where the editing controls would show up) when not editing, and instead render an identical `<div>` with the editing contents when the component was in edit mode.